# Wireshark Openflow support not working

Tags: 14.10, wireshark

I installed `mininet` to see Openflow in action. However when I installed `wireshark` with `apt-get` and with the script provided by `mininet`, but I got the same error:

```
$ sudo wireshark
21:18:34          Warn Could not compile "of" in colorfilters file.
"of" is neither a field nor a protocol name.
$ wireshark
21:18:49          Warn Could not compile "of" in colorfilters file.
"of" is neither a field nor a protocol name.
```

Indeed I couldn't use the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark is correct; "of" is, in fact, neither a field nor a protocol name.

"openflow", however, is, as are "openflow_v4" for Openflow-v4-specific fields and "openflow_v5" for Openflow-v5-specific fields.  Make sure you have Wireshark 1.12 or later (earlier versions didn't *have* Openflow support), and fix the color filters to use the correct field and protocol names.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu does not have Wireshark 1.12 any earlier than 14.10 (Utopic) - this will *not* work on earlier versions.

Comment: ...unless you install your own version of Wireshark, rather than relying on the OS supplier.

Comment: true, however most users aren't going to compile software themselves (which is why I made a Wireshark PPA for my installing the newer Wireshark on older systems)